# Please help with understanding a logic definition: Subformula

Tags: logic, definition

Alright, so I am reading "Computability and Logic" by Boolos and Jeffrey, specifically I'm on chapter 9 "A Precis of First-Order Logic: Syntax. There has been more than a handful of definitions in this chapter, and I believe I've come to be able to understand what each of them are except one in particular which begins on pg. 110. Namely, the following:

"We officially define a string of consecutive symbols within a given formula to be a ${subformula}$ of the given formula if it is itself a formula."

So, I've tried to break this down and see where I am getting confused. I followed entirely what is being said until "...if it is itself a formula." The reason I am getting confused is why is this last part added? I was given a formula shouldn't "it" be a formula if that is what we are given?

Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: You were indeed given a formula, but, now you are looking at a substring. That substring may, or, may not be a formula. If it is, it is a subformula of the original formula.

Comment: Awesome! Thanks James!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know what notation B&J use, but the point will be something like this.  If you have a formula
$$\forall x (P(x)\to(\neg Q(x)))$$
then for example
$$x(P$$
is a string of consecutive symbols from this formula.  However $x(P$ is not a grammatically (syntactically) correct formula, therefore it is not a subformula.

On the other hand, $P(x)$ is a string of consecutive symbols from the above formula, and $P(x)$ is itself a grammatically correct formula, so $P(x)$ is a subformula of the above.

Comment: Once again David, you are amazing, your explanations are lucid, and you are very kind to help me out!

Comment: David, my class is currently using Computability and Logic for a class named Intermediate Logic. I enjoy the book, but I was wondering if you had any suggestions for a possible supplement?

Comment: See if [these notes](http://web.maths.unsw.edu.au/~angell/3421/) help.  The notes are copyright so please do not make multiple copies, but you are welcome to keep a (hard or soft) copy for yourself.

Comment: Wow, okay I'll check them out sometime today. Thanks a million David!